# What is the best method to use the cache for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, caching, windows-phone-8, localdatacache

I am making a app in windows phone sdk 8 and I was wondering what the best method is to store local data. I want to use this for storing data and optimize memory usage. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what kind of data are you storing? (configuration like xml / text) or binary (pictures, audio) ?

Comment: I want to store text/strings

Comment: How many strings? There is no "best" way. It might be to put them in a database, or store in file, or realize that you may not have enough that it matters.

Comment: Use static type to implement cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store strings then you can use IsolatedStorageSettings

Basically the easiest way to put data into WP7 IsolatedStorage is to use the IsolatedStorageSettings class which  is a Dictionary that stores key-value pairs in isolated storage.

Sample storage and retrieval

```
//storage
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = your string;
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

//retrieval
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State") == true)
 {
 var object= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] as string;
 //Remove the state now
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("State");
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
 }
```

also, just check [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings) link

Comment: Isolated settings really isn't a cache, and may introduce other performance issues and use disk space unnecessarily unless it is properly managed.

Comment: Yes it is not the best way, probably the best way to store could be keeping it inside database or making a file and then storing it. But, what if there is only a single string?

Comment: A single string or even a reasonable number could be easily cached in a Dictionary. The question is at least partly about a cache given the title, not persistent storage.